# Need help to build a logic sequence to handle the scenario explained

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

This is the situation:

There is an interface with many input fields and a 'Save' button to update the inputs.
Saving will include many processes such as validation, user confirmation, adding comments or cancelling update.

To move away from this interface there are many options like click on tabs, click on different buttons, pressing keyboard shortcuts and other more.

The expected behavior when user tries to move away is the system should check for not updated fields and if any it should ask the use to update or ignore it.

If the user choose 'Ignore', no problem, proceed with the navigation.

But If the user choose 'Update' then the system should pause the current navigation and do the update handler witch contains many other procedures. After successful completion of these updating procedures the system should continue with paused interface navigation process from the point it is paused.

For a sample:

```
//something like this
$('#nxtPage').live("click", function(){
  if (any field value changed){
    var usrConf = confirm('You wanna update?')
    if (usrConf){
      // proceed with the updating processes by calling them
      callDefaultFldUpdate(); // where this function includes many other procedures, so the return status wont help.
    }
  }
  // the default page navigation process starts here
  moveToNextPage();
}
```

So after the update procedures the system should continue with navigation procedure.

Hope the situation is clear and expecting useful suggestions from you all to build this logic using javascript && jquery.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a global variable, something like `isChanged = false;` then bind a function to form change event.

```
$(document).on('change', 'form', function(){
    window.isChanged = true;
}
```

validate against the `isChanged` variable in your code where it says, for example

`if (any field value changed){` can say `if(isChanged == true){`

Comment: Thank you, I'm ok upto capturing user option 'Update' or 'Ignore'.
When it is 'Update' problem starts...